# Multiple authentication levels in a RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

## Scenario

We are building a new RESTful API for our web application. This API will serve our mobile applications, our web application and authorised customers.

We are using Apigility to build the API and are making use of the OAuth2 implementation it provides.

Currently, our web application relies on a `users`  table, with permissions assigned to each user. These users simply log-in using a web form, and the session is then stored and appropriate permissions checked upon access.

We want to be able to authenticate API access (such as our web app, and authorised customers), so no unauthorised access to the API can happen. However, we also want to authorize the permissions at a user level, therefore some sort of user authentication must also happen as well.

Any authorised access to the API may use a different user, so relying on a single user per client will not work, especially since the permissions are on a per user basis. We also do not want any user to be able to use the API without prior authentication, so wanted to avoid adding every user as a client to OAuth2.

#### For example:

The web app is authenticated with the API with two users using it:

`UserA` has user management permissions

`UserB` does not have user management permissions

Therefore, `UserA` can `POST` to `/users` and receive a `200 OK` while `UserB` should receive a `403 Forbidden`.

## What we have tried

We have created an example application, and have successfully set up authentication using OAuth2 for the high-level clients and can make calls as expected. But we have not been able to create an authorization model for our users based on this.

We though adding a custom HTTP header with a user token that is provided after an authenticated call to `/user/login`. But we are not sure if this is the correct method.

## The question

How can we both authenticate the high-level clients (such as our web app, or authorised customers) but then authorize access based on the user actually using the system?

Comment: How did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options available to you:

**Token-level permissions**

You can provide different tokens for each user account, and tie permissions to the token. This runs the risk of the wrong tokens being mixed up with the wrong users. However, this also has the advantage of not having to maintain a user<->token relationship, as the permission is decided at the token level. How you decide which token to generate can be tricky.

**User-level permissions**

You can tie a user account to a token and that user can then be given read/write permissions. This reduces the risk of a user having a wrong token as they're linked. With this method, you can use the same method of token generation for all user accounts as the token is ignorant of the permission, but does allow them "access" to the API (thus preventing unauthorised access).

I've deliberately avoided mentioning specific types of authentication tokens, as these two concepts can apply to most of the popular choices on the web (token-based, OAuth based).

Comment: I think the question is more about how you manage the two-pronged auth scenario. You need to authenticate the API user, and then the end user who is providing their own credentials. The API user may have permission to do anything as long as the user credentials are appropriate. However, depending on the implementation, the API user may have restricted access. How does that work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in regards to the user-level permissions, are you saying the authentication should also be done there? As @AntTheKnee has said, we are looking at authenticating the API user (such as our web-app) first, then using the a secondary authentication/authorization for the user, after the API user is authenticated. Is this possible with your method?

Comment: @LewisChadwick In the past I've implemented a service that uses a pair of tokens to authenticate an "app" and then a "session", but in your case you could tie that session token to a user's account. User tokens can be generated tying a user and an app to a "user" token. You have to manage an extra set of tokens but this gives you the granularity you want.

Comment: @phalt are you saying that we should authenticate the API user, then the end-user, and provide a single token after this process which effectively means "API user and end user" all in one? If so, I think I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

OAuth has no [concept of Identity](http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/).

You should look into using [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) which is a profile on top of Oauth 2.0.